# Shrew Soft VPN - "session terminated by gateway"

Tags: vpn, session, shrew

I am running Windows 7 64-bit. I use Shew Soft VPN to connect to several VPNs. Everything was working fine until a few days ago, but now, every time I connect to any VPN, it seems to connect but then immediately disconnects with the message "session terminated by gateway" as soon as I try to pass any traffic through it (web browsing, ftp, etc). Basic error messages are below:

```
attached to key daemon ...
peer configured
iskamp proposal configured
esp proposal configured
client configured
local id configured
remote id configured
pre-shared key configured
bringing up tunnel ...
network device configured
tunnel enabled
(Comment: this occurs when there is web traffic)
session terminated by gateway
tunnel disabled
detached from key daemon
```

I am using Shrew Soft VPN version 2.2.0. I currently have the firewall disabled, so it doesn't seem like that would be the issue.

I can post error logs if necessary.

Comment: Are you in control of the VPNs you're connecting to?

Comment: No, I am not. And they are for different companies so it seems unlikely to be on their end. I should also add that I have coworkers who are connecting with the same software from different locations without issue.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid this question is off-topic for here. You need to work with the IT departments that manage the VPN servers, as they're the only ones that have authoritative information on how things are configured and how to get your access fixed up.

Comment: Is there someplace else I can post it? No one else is having issues and I'm fairly certain it's a modem configuration issue, not a VPN setup issues since the VPNs are from different companies and were all working previously.